# Best battery to power a Microcontroller outdoors

Tags: batteries, solar-cell, lipo

I live in a place where the temperatures can range from -20°C to +40°C in different seasons. I need to power a small micro-controller that uses very low energy with a solar panel and a battery. Which kind of battery is more suitable for this work? It must have the following characteristics:

- It should resist to temperatures from -20°C to +40°C.
- It's not important to store a lot of energy, 500mAh will be fine.
- It should output at least 5V. If less I will have to put two or more batteries in series.
- It should not require maintenance.
- It should live for a decade or more.
- It will be pretty always charged since the solar panel will be directly connected to it (or maybe, via software, I can make some cycles of charge/discharge).

which battery do you recommend?

**Explanation of the project**

I'm following an IoT course at my university, and I'm free to propose a custom project that will be part of the final exam. I thought about a series of small boxes that will allow us to check if a parking slot is free or not. The box will be build with my 3D-printer and it will include: a small solar panel with a maximum power of 9V * 50mA in the best case (size 60x80mm); a battery of at least 500mA that will be charged by the solar panel; a proximity/distance waterproof sensor that will check if a car is parked on the slot; a MCU with WiFi to send data to an other sensor or to a master with a raspberry pi. I will take inspiration from internet for the routing of packets through this "network" of boxes. Not all boxes will be directly connected to the master box.... We are already experimenting plastics to build a box strong enough to resist to the wheels of a car. The solar panel will be protected with a non-scratchable piece of plexiglass. Sensors will be cleaned from leaves and earth by rain, by road-cleaners and by the wind. Our roads are very clean. The major problem we are facing is to choose the best battery to be used in this "extreme" application. In winter, at night, the temperatures can drop up to -20°C while in summer, during sunny days, it's possible to reach +40°C.
Finally, we will develop an App that will give you the nearest free parking slot.

Comment: What is a lot of energy? How much current is required? What voltage do you need? Better requirements are needed. -20 is pretty cold, will you need to run a heater?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Keep in mind that questions about optimization (i.e., *"What is the best ...?"*) require a definition about what problem dimensions are to be optimized for your application, such as size, speed, energy consumpation, user experience, etc. Since these can't be optimized all at once, you need to have a good idea of which ones are most important to you, and be able to articulate that clearly to us.

Comment: @Colin I’ve updated my question

Comment: [This article](https://www.electrochem.org/redcat-blog/enabling-ultra-low-temperature-batteries/) says *"Currently, lithium-ion batteries stop operating around -20° Celsius."*

Comment: Is -20°C storage temperature or will it also be charged and discharged?

Comment: It should be working continuously for some years

Comment: Which one would you think to fit your application, from this article, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_commercial_battery_types ?

Comment: I've seen it, but it does not take into account the working temperatures.

Comment: I've added a requirement, I forgot that once the system is started, it will not be possible to do maintenance

Comment: How low is "very low energy"? How did you calculate 500mAhr? What is the charge/discharge cycle like (i.e. does it need to standby for years, months, or just make it through the night? ).

Comment: I’ve written that it will be working all the day because of the possibility of clouds, rains.....the system will wake up every 1/2 minutes to check for changes and eventually send them via wifi to a master. Then it will be back to sleep. The mcu board consumes about 10mA when active and less then 80uA when sleeping. 500mAh should be enough for a couple of days.

Comment: And who will clean up your solar panel after snow?

Comment: I've updated my question with project details

Comment: I see quite a few issues with your project. Is the sensor going to be under the car? So when a park is parked, there will be very little light if at all to charge the battery. Given the extreme temperatures, I suppose you are quite far north, which in turn means short days, and less opportunity for the battery to recharge. And that's not counting the times the sensor is covered by leaves, dirt or snow. Also, if your sensor is buried in the ground with a car on top of it, it's not optimal for wireless communication.

Comment: Also, you should probably not connect your solar panel directly to your battery: most batteries need a specific voltage to charge, as well as a specific current range. Solar cells can deliver very, very variable output, so you may be most of the time either above max voltage or below min voltage. Why do you need 5V? Most low power MCUs are 3.3V or less. Is that for the sensor itself? Note that if you count on relaying via other nodes, those nodes will need to be powered a lot more frequently (or all the time) to receive the messages and relay them.

Comment: Also note that most battery technologies that do operate at -20 will have a much, much lower performance at those temperatures. Some will allow discharging but not charging (and become very dangerous if you try to charge them at those temperatures).

Comment: Thank you for your interesting. First of all, there will be no more than 4/5 steps from the master to the farther node. My MCU requires a voltage from 4.5V to 10V, probably because of the WiFi module, and it will absorb no more than 10mA. Maybe I will redesign the box to include a bigger battery. So I made some test on the solar panel. With direct solar light with an angle from up to 45° the voltage is over 8V. If the solar panel is not directly illuminated but the sky is clear and there is the sun, the voltage stays at about 7.3-7.4V.

Comment: I will control the voltage of the solar panel and decide to charge the battery only if the voltage is high enough and only if the temperature is above some threshold, for example 0 celsius degrees.

Comment: Whether you have 1 step or more does not change the fact that relaying nodes will need to be active a lot more often. What MCU are you planning to use? Most MCUs with Wi-Fi I know of run at 3.3V, definitely not at 10V. And I'm quite surprised by the 10mA figure, WiFi TX usually eats an order of magnitude more than that. Can you tell us the location? Is -20 something usual, or is it just the freaky once in 10 years episode? Also, what kind of sensor are you planning to use?

Comment: We are planning to use this board: NodeMCU v3.2. It's cheap, WiFi enabled and Arduino-compatible. I'm not saying that it works with 10V but that it can work with an input voltage between 4.5V and 10V. Probably it has an internal voltage regulator. I'm now reading in this [post](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/37583/nodemcu-powered-with-battery-and-use-wifi/37637#37637) that there can be peaks up to 200mA during wifi use, but the seller on ebay wrote about an average of 10-15mA when active. Where can I find some exact specifications about this MCU?

Comment: @LucaDiLiello NodeMCUs are based on the [ESP8266](https://www.espressif.com/en/products/hardware/esp8266ex/overview). Wi-Fi TX uses 100-200 mA, Wi-Fi RX 50-60 mA. Your actual average power draw depends a lot on what you do exactly. The ESP8266 itself runs at 3.3V. There are tons of different NodeMCU variants from many different suppliers, so the exact details of input voltage may vary. Note that there are also lots of other ESP8266 boards. Depending on the exact board and the programming environment you may also get very different power characteristics, especially when it comes to sleep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing your exact requirements, I would recommend you Ni-Mh AA batteries with nominal voltage of 1.2V (e.g. Eneloop brand) The standard ones have operating range down to -20deg C and they have very high energy density. But attention: At -20deg C you need to fine control the charging voltage and current. See this site for details: [batteryuniversity.com](https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_at_high_and_low_temperatures)

Comment: I've updated my question with details

Comment: Given that probably with very low temperatures there will no be solar power to charge the batteries, at the moment your option is the best. thanks

Comment: Thanks. But if you do not intend to use rechargeable batteries, then primary cells like Li-iron-disulfide (energizer) would be even better for your project.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you need a couple of alkaline D cells.  Run your micro off solar when the sun shines and off the batteries at night.  10 years might be pushing the life of the batteries but not by much.
You can isolate the batteries with a Schottkey diode.

Comment: Rechargeable alkaline batteries?

Comment: @LucaDiLiello, not rechargeable, but "alternate power", solar when sun shines, battery when not. Saves battery life.

Comment: 10 years is 88,000 hours. Waking up every 30 sec with 10 mA consumption for 1 s gives you, say, 0.3 mA average. Assuming 30% solar,  you will need a battery of about 18,000 -20,000 mAh, which is about a good D-cell capacity at this discharge rate. So this might work. After doing this estimate, +1

Comment: It’s a good idea, but there is no space for 4 D cells. Moreover, i think that waking up, reading a sensor and send the result via wifi will take more than a second, maybe 2 or 3.

Comment: @LucaDiLiello Depending on the MCU and your network, it may be a lot more than 2 or 3. Hint: don't use DHCP.

Comment: I will not use DHCP with such a small network. I will create simple routing tables sending a message in broadcast from the master such that each node will remember the channel on which it received the message. Then each node will send its data to that other node. Given that a box will cover 2 parking slots, there will be no more than 15 nodes on the same network (connected to the same master).

Answer (score 1):

Your combined requirements

- It should resist to temperatures from -20°C (to +40°C.)
- It should live for a decade or more.

sort out any standard accumulator but lead. Lithium may reach this but I personally won't count on the quality of the cells I could get my hands on. Car batteries of high quality are in contrary available in the next car parts shop.

As an alternative, you may want to oversize your accumulator and put it into an electrical heated, insulated compartment. Also good for the electronics. Condensation is hell.

Comment: I've updated my answer......this is the reason why it should live for many years without maintenance

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do, but these two items from your requirements are among the hardest things to do in engineering. They give 50-year practice engineers an uneasy feeling and the need to do more testing, using a climate chamber and doing a lot of calculations just for that. And still it could fail in a year without warning because of some thing you haven't thought about. You project is complex. You have hundreds of such pits you haven't thought about yet.

Comment: The reason why most of these "maker" style things haven't been rolled out isn't nobody thought about it yet, but poor reliablity (if poor cost performance doesn't suffice to cancel it). Don't betray yourself. If you want to create such a thing, declare it art. It's allowed to fail then. People may share your dream and not complain about the sillyness.

Comment: I'm doing this project for an university course and probably (or for sure) it will never be implemented. Despite this, it will be very interesting to create such a simple plug-and-play box to monitor parking slots. You are right, there are many difficulties to face wrt the batteries and the temperature, but I'm sure that in some years there will be new technologies available. At the moment, I will only succeed in building a first working prototype.

Comment: Moreover, I'm a student of computer science and this electronic problems will not be so important. But it should work....

Comment: Step back from those two requirements then. It will make your life much easier. There's no sense in strengthening random parts. Make it disposable. Or think again, put it on a pole (much less water problems up there) and use a radar module to check the parking space in front.

Comment: Regarding the sensor, we have found a cheap ultrasonic waterproof sensor that has not a great precision but we have only to know if a car is present, not the exact distance. I wrote this strict requirements to find the best battery-tech. Obviously I will have to make choices and trade-offs between specifications. I finally decided to use NiMH batteries as they seems to be the most similar to what I'm searching.

Comment: @LucaDiLiello I don't have any experience with those, but I doubt an ultrasonic sensor is the right choice for an unattended, outdoor, ground level sensor that is supposed to last for years. Also don't forget those use power.